# Jasmine - using forEach to test that key/value pairs in array of objects are defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach, jasmine

I have an array of objects called allFeeds.  Each object has a "name" key, which has an associated value called "url".  I am trying to write a test in Jasmine that loops through the array and tests each object to ensures no "url" value is "undefined".  My code is below.  I have tried a couple iterations of the syntax/logic to no avail.

```
    it('each object in allFeeds array should have a URL value associated with each key', function() {
          allFeeds.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                var x = arrayItem.url
                return x;
            });
          expect(x).not.toBeUndefined();
       });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you place your 'check' at the wrong position.

```
it('each object in allFeeds array should have a URL value associated with each key', function() {
    allFeeds.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        var x = arrayItem.url
        // Check 'x' here
        expect(x).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
    // Worng position - 'x' exists only in the loop
    // expect(x).not.toBeUndefined();
});
```